# Expand column into multiple columns in postgres

Tags: sql, postgresql

Basically this is the result that I get from the fiddle that you can find here: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/48a30/59

My question is how can you turn the result below

```
update_record
(1,t)
(null)
(3,t)
(null)
(5,t)
(null)
```

into the following

```
col1 | col2
-----+-----
1    | t
3    | t
5    | t
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically, functions which return set of rows should be called in the FROM clause. In this way you will get regular columns instead of records in the resultset.

```
SELECT upd.*
FROM input,
update_record(input) AS upd
WHERE upd.id IS NOT NULL

 id | certified 
----+-----------
  1 | t
  3 | t
  5 | t
(3 rows)
```

[SQLFiddle.](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/fe0c8/3)